# How to write Test cases for Javafx Controllers?

Tags: maven, javafx, junit5

I have written this test class for javafx application.

```
class HelloApplicationTest extends GuiTest {

@Override
protected Parent getRootNode() {
    Parent parent = null;
    try {
        parent = FXMLLoader.load((getResource("hello-view.fxml")));
        return parent;
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {

    }
    return parent;
}
@Test
void add_button() {
    Button add_btn_1=find("#add_btn");
    assertFalse(add_btn_1.disableProperty().get());
    FxAssert.verifyThat("#add_btn", LabeledMatchers.hasText("Add"));
}
}
```

I am getting error like this -> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.util.Iterator javafx.stage.Window.impl_getWindows()'

```
<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="350.0" prefWidth="666.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/18" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.example.fxml_db.HelloController">
   <children>
   <Label layoutX="14.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="39.0" prefWidth="295.0" text="Add and View Employee:">
      <font>
        <Font name="System Bold" size="24.0" />
      </font>
   </Label>
  <Label layoutX="22.0" layoutY="93.0" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="124.0" text="Name:" />
  <Label layoutX="22.0" layoutY="136.0" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="124.0" text="Address:" />
  <Label layoutX="22.0" layoutY="181.0" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="124.0" text="Age:" />
  <TextField fx:id="name" layoutX="106.0" layoutY="94.0" />
  <TextField fx:id="address" layoutX="106.0" layoutY="137.0" />
  <TextField fx:id="age" layoutX="106.0" layoutY="182.0" />
  <Button fx:id="add_btn" layoutX="127.0" layoutY="223.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#add_details" text="Add" />
  <TableView fx:id="table" layoutX="342.0" layoutY="51.0" prefHeight="260.0" prefWidth="305.0">
    <columns>
      <TableColumn fx:id="idcol" prefWidth="39.33331298828125" text="ID" />
      <TableColumn fx:id="namecol" prefWidth="111.3333740234375" text="Name" />
        <TableColumn fx:id="addresscol" prefWidth="110.00003051757812" text="Address" />
        <TableColumn fx:id="agecol" prefWidth="40.6666259765625" text="Age" />
    </columns>
  </TableView>
  <Button fx:id="connect_db" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="310.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#connect" text="Connect DB" />
  <Button layoutX="200.0" layoutY="223.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#clear_data" text="Clear" />
   </children>
    </AnchorPane>
```

I am not able to fetch the components form the .fxml file. this is my .fxml code

Comment: What is GuiTest?  What is the full stack trace of your error?  What are your build dependencies?  What are your JDK/JavaFX versions?  What is a link to the documentation you followed to create your test case? The general question "How to write Test cases for Javafx Controllers?"  is too broad to be answered here (something more specific might be OK).  You can edit the question to improve it.

Comment: Have you tried [`TestFX`](https://github.com/TestFX/TestFX)?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.